# how to change program name in setup UAC with installshield

Tags: setup, c#, installshield

I am trying to create a setup.exe using limited edition of Installshield, but I am not able to  change the program name show in the user account control form. However when I uninstall, the program name shows the correct one. Please help me.

Comment: What version of install shield limited edition exactly?

Comment: install shield 2013 @Ramhound

Answer (score 0):

Inside "(1) Organise Your Setup", "General Information". The first field is "Product Name"